# Como resgatar dados do sqlite3 com python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Tenho um aplicativo em tkinter(Cadastro básico que todo aprendiz faz) onde salvei os dados no sqlite3, porém estou tendo dificuldades na hora de resgatar esses dados.
O que eu preciso exatamente é:

- Que ele me retorne dentro de uma combobox o nome de cada pessoa cadastrada
- E também todos os dados de cada usuário
  Porém não consigo de jeito nenhum tirar essas informações de dentro da lista, tentei todo tipo de laço possível, mas me retorna erro.
  Segue abaixo um print do programa e os código pertinentes ao banco:
- qualquer ajuda será bem vinda, já tentei executar os vários exemplos da documentação e nada, e preciso finalizar este trabalho. Deixo meu agradecimento a quem me ajudar...
- 

```
def consulta_BD(self):
    conexao = sqlite3.connect("saveData.db")
    c = conexao.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    c = conexao.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM dadosDoUsuario")
    r = c.fetchall()
    consulta = [dict(row) for row in r]
    return consulta
    c.close()
    conexao.close()

def commandButtonSalvar(self):
    conexao = sqlite3.connect("saveData.db")
    c = conexao.cursor()
    # id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    c.execute(
        """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dadosDoUsuario (
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    data_nasc TEXT,
    sexo TEXT,
    telefone TEXT,
    celular TEXT,
    rg TEXT,
    cpf TEXT,
    endereco TEXT,
    email TEXT);
        """
    )
    c.execute(
        "INSERT INTO dadosDoUsuario VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        (
            self.entry_nome.get(),
            self.dateEntry.get(),
            self.combobox_sexo.get(),
            self.entryTelef.get(),
            self.entryCelular.get(),
            self.entryRG.get(),
            self.entryCPF.get(),
            self.entryEnd.get("1.0", "end"),
            self.entryEmail.get(),
        ),
    )
    conexao.commit()
    conexao.close()
    self.mensagem('info', 'Atenção!', 'Cadastro salvo!')
    self.clear()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Após muita pesquisa e vários testes alterei o trecho de código abaixo que fez tudo funcionar direinho.

```
self.nomes = []

def consulta_BD(self):
        conexao = sqlite3.connect("saveData.db")
        cursor = conexao.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dadosDoUsuario ORDER BY nome")
        r = cursor.fetchall()

        for n in r:
            self.nomes.append(n[1].title())
        return self.nomes
```

Deixo aqui registrado caso alguém precise desta solução, de qualquer forma muito obrigado a todos...